# How to upload base64 image to s3 from rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am making an ajax reject to my controller with some data and base64 image and now I want to upload this image to s3 and replace base64 with the image url. I am following this https://sebastiandobrincu.com/blog/how-to-upload-images-to-rails-api-using-s3

```
 def split_base64(uri_str)
          if uri_str.match(%r{^data:(.*?);(.*?),(.*)$})
            uri = Hash.new
            uri[:type] = $1 # "image/gif"
            uri[:encoder] = $2 # "base64"
            uri[:data] = $3 # data string
            uri[:extension] = $1.split('/')[1] # "gif"
            return uri
          else
            return nil
          end
end

def convert_data_uri_to_upload(image_url)            
            image_data = split_base64(image_url)
            image_data_string = image_data[:data]
            image_data_binary = Base64.decode64(image_data_string)

            temp_img_file = Tempfile.new("")
            temp_img_file.binmode
            temp_img_file << image_data_binary
            temp_img_file.rewind

            img_params = {:filename => "image.#{image_data[:extension]}", :type => image_data[:type], :tempfile => temp_img_file}
            uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(img_params)
          end
    return uploaded_file    
end
```

Now from my controller I am passing 
`convert_data_uri_to_upload(base64_image)`

Now I don't know where to write the AWS credentials. According to the url I have to write the credentials in Fog.rb file but I don't have any such file. I have created one ImageUploader inside uploader folder which extends CarrierWave and wrote the configurations but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dotenv ruby gem follow this : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dotenv-rails/2.1.1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.